# Can you use Generics with a web service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, generics, serialization

Is it possible to have a method like this on a WCF service contract, and call it from a SOAP client?

```
TContentType GetTopics<TContentType>() where TContentType : ContentItem
```

I think generics are serializable, so perhaps it just depends if the client can support them? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the actual OperationContract must be about a concrete type. You could derive from a generic like this, but not publish it directly.

You cannot use overloading either.

Comment: You use overloading if you specify a different Name in the OperationContract attribute of each overload.